# Convert PDF to something editable without losing all formatting

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, file-conversion

I am aware of solutions that allow one to [extract text from a pdf file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/how-to-convert-a-pdf-file-into-a-text-file). Are there any practical solutions on the Mac to extract rich text and layout from a PDF, or somehow convert a PDF into some editable format without losing all formatting, and without multi-column layouts ending up with the text from each column interwoven?

Comment: That's pretty much the Holy Grail you're talking about. As far as I know, you probably won't find a perfect solution--just something sort of close to it. PDF's are notoriously difficult to convert properly, let alone perfectly.

Comment: Any approximation of accurate is better than doing it all by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to edit the content of the PDF, Adobe Acrobat (full version) can do that. It can change/add/delete text, images, objects, etc.

Comment: D'oh. I hadn't even thought of that route. Good call. So obvious, and yet I was so oblivious.

Answer (score 2):

A good converting site is [zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com). Not perfect, but quite good!

Comment: What does good and perfect mean in this context, what is your experience with the service?

Comment: zamzar didn't work for my converting from a PDF to HTML, but it did successfully convert (the same PDF) to DOCX.